# MSTest TestMethod Dependency Injection

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dependency-injection, mstest

I'm using a DI container and I want to do MSTest (VS 2010) unit tests with instances resolved from the container.

I'd like to get these instances injected into my TestMethod or at least my TestClass. Is this possible?

Right now my TestMethods directly call `container.Resolve<T>(xxx)` which I'd prefer to avoid so that my injection testing is more realistic.

Answer (score 10):

The instantiation of the test class happens deeply in the internal classes of the MSTest framework so injecting dependencies into it would be a challenging task.

Answer (score 7):

The main reason -for me- for writing code according to the Dependency Injection pattern and using IoC frameworks is to get testable code. Using a IoC container in your test code however, will get the opposite result. From your question I can see that you are already experiencing this.

This is especially the problem when using the Service Locator (SL) pattern instead of the Dependency Injection (DI) pattern. With the SL pattern, a class calls the IoC container (or an abstraction of such a container) directly, instead of supplying the class with the dependencies it needs (using constructor injection). Because classes are calling the container directly, you need to configure that container in your test environment as well. This is painful because the test configuration or fake objects is often gets very complex, because you often want to influence the behavior of a fake on a per test basis, while keeping things thread-safe, because testing frameworks might run your tests in parallel (MSTest does this). I know I wrote some crazy thread-safe test code in the past, before I found out that I was doing it all wrong :-(.

So you should use the DI pattern in your application code and in your tests you should hook up those dependencies manually. For instance, when having tests for a `HomeController` class that depends on a `ICustomerService` class, you should typically have a `CreateController()` or `CreateValidController` factory method in your test class that centralizes the creation of that `HomeController`. This saves you from writing those dependencies in every test and thus creating a maintenance nightmare in your test code. In this factory method you inject for instance a `FakeCustomerService` class manually, by doing something like this:

```
private static HomeController CreateController(
    InMemoryDataMapper mapper)
{
    var uowFactory = new FakeNorthwindUnitOfWorkFactory()
    {
        UnitOfWork = new NorthwindUnitOfWork(mapper);
    };

    return new HomeController(new FakeCustomerService(uowFactory));
}
```

How such a factory method looks like of course depends (no pun intended) on how the dependency structure of the `HomeController` looks like.

Long story short, do not try to do dependency injection in your test code the same way as you want to do in your application code. Not only do test frameworks make it very hard to do this, it would mean you have to configure your IoC framework for your test environment, in which case you will be heading to failure. Unfortunately, I talk from experience.

Comment: I'm not using a SL pattern, fortunately...only constructor injection. I thought I recall googling that exact question on parallel tests because I had the same concern and seeing MSBuild doesn't run tests in parallel by default, but I'm probably wrong.

Comment: So I should be duplicating the dependency awareness AND lifetime configuration in all my test code? In other words, lets say I have a component that is a singleton in the container and then should be injected into a constructor of 5 transient components that are required for some test? I need to do a set up for that test that knows to manually instantiate the instance of the singleton and keep it around as a singleton to get injected into each dependent component that I instantiate manually? What if the component changes to not be a singleton? I have to rewrite all my test setup code for this?

Comment: And what about testing the availability of components or services to be injected into instance constructors? If I do instantiation manually, I miss out on testing this key piece of functionality. I consider it key, because maintaining state is usually one of the more delicate parts of programming and if I'm not testing the availability of components, then I'm missing out on testing the validity of state management altogether, right? One of my strongest beliefs in programming is DRY. More specifically "Don't maintain state in two places!".

Comment: I never experienced a situation where I also needed to inject a singleton in my test objects. When I inject a fake as depedency, I always create a new object per test. So the lifestyle is not important in your tests, as it shouldn't be for the classes that use that dependency.

Comment: If you have some classes that are injected as singletons and maintain some state (or cache, or what ever) you probably want to test this separately. If you use this singleton with state in your tests, you start getting tests depending on each other, which makes it very hard to keep tests trustworthy. What I tent to do however, is having a test project on the root application itself (usually web application or web service), and have a few tests that verify the DI configuration.

Comment: "The main reason for writing code according to the Dependency Injection pattern and using IoC frameworks is to get testable code." -> no

Comment: @Steven: testability is a consequence, not the main reason.

Comment: Mauricio, any other  thoughts?

Comment: Mauricio is right. Cost-effectiveness is the main reason. To be cost-effective we need maintainable software. Testability helps in achieving maintainable (changeable) software. Dependency injection can help in getting maintainable software even without automated testing. However, using the DI pattern on every single place in your code, will result in the opposite effect. For this reason, I usually decide to use DI only in parts of my software where it helps me with writing (unit) tests. So what I should have written was: "The main reason -for me- for writing code...".